# Profile List View Filteration

Tags: administration, profile, list-view, criteria-filter

What filetrs can I apply to profile list view to get Profiles that have access to particular record type of Case?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this using Profile list view filters.  You can't apply such filters.

Either you need to manually search them or try your hand on Metadata API and write your own custom logic to find the profile details.